Max queue depth in Hyper-V VM?
For a VM on Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V, what is the max queue depth of a scsi controller and for each disk? I just can't find the number for this.
For VMware I see that the paravirtual scsi controller in a VM can go to 1024 queue depth, but I can't find this for Hyper-V VMs.
Not asking on how to monitor the queue depth. Searching for the max value. Also this is not iSCSI or HBA queue depth, but the queue depth inside the Windows VM running on a Hyper-V host with (virtual) SCSI controller.

This question is similar to: max iSCSI initiator session. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
